# sionna python package missing BCJRDecoder and other parts

Tags: python, import, jupyter

I'm trying to run the sionna jupyter notebook [5G Channel Coding and Rate-Matching: Polar vs. LDPC Codes](https://nvlabs.github.io/sionna/examples/5G_Channel_Coding_Polar_vs_LDPC_Codes.html). I get a few errors about parts of sionna which cannot be found. They seem to be missing, but most are present. The first error that I encounter is

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'BCJRDecoder' from 'sionna.fec.conv'
```

The error originates from line 15 of code snippet 3 of the notebook. Here is the line:

```
from sionna.fec.conv import ConvEncoder, ViterbiDecoder, BCJRDecoder
```

Additionally, the following can't be found:

```
sionna.fec.turbo
sionna.fec.linear
```

Many other parts of sionna are present. The problems that I experience in the jupyter notebook are the same on the command line. Here are some examples:

```
python -c 'from sionna.fec.conv import ConvEncoder'  # works
python -c 'from sionna.fec.conv import BCJRDecoder'  # ImportError: cannot import name 'BCJRDecoder' from 'sionna.fec.conv'
python -c 'import sionna.fec'  # works
python -c 'import sionna.fec.turbo'  # ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sionna.fec.turbo'
python -c 'import sionna.fec.linear'  # ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sionna.fec.linear'
```

What's wrong here and how to fix it?

My verisons:

```
Linux Mint 21.1
Python 3.10.9
sionna 0.10.0
```

Comment: Additionally, please help me with the vocabulary. Is it correct that `sionna` (like in `pip install sionna`) is a package, `sionna.fec.conv` is a module, more specifically a sub-module of the module `sionna.fec`? And `ConvEncoder` is a class inside of the module `sionna.fec.conv`?

Answer (score 0):

My version of sionna was 0.10.0, which is outdated. Uninstalling and re-installing sionna updated it to version 0.14.0 and it solved the problem.

For command line:

```
python -m pip uninstall --no-input --yes sionna
python -m pip install --no-input sionna
```

To achieve the same in the jupyter notebook's environment, use this in a code snippet:

```
import os
os.system("python -m pip uninstall --no-input --yes sionna")
os.system("python -m pip install --no-input sionna")
```

It's still a mystery to me why sionna version 0.10.0 was installed. I had completely reinstalled the PC just days ago from scratch with OS and everything, but the sionna version that got initially installed was superseded since 9 months.